# How to set texture on model programmatically

Tags: 3d, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to make the apple textured by putting in these codes:

```
GameObject cube = Instantiate(Resources.Load("apple", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
Texture my3dModelTexture = Resources.Load("Textures/apple2", typeof(Texture)) as Texture;
cube.renderer.material.mainTexture = my3dModelTexture;
```

However, my apple appeared to be untextured. But then I tried the same concept on a cube, and it is working.

```
GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
```

Could someone please help? I have been trying a lot of methods, but none of them seem to work and I still cant find the reason why.

Comment: `Resources.Load` will return null if no such resource is found; the `as` operator will return null if the input is null or has a type that can't be cast successfully. If you set the material's texture to null, you'll get an untextured object. So, you might run MonoDevelop's debugger or use `Debug.Log()` to check: are you setting a null texture? Barring that, are you using a material/shader that accepts a texture parameter in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

//assuming there is image file apple.png or jpg in the resource folder

```
Texture2D tex = Resources.Load(apple) as Texture2D;
if(tex == null)
    Debug.LogError("Error loading image");
else
    Debug.Log ("Scuccess in loading image");
cube.renderer.material.mainTexture = tex;
```